# .split() if value exists regardless

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have HTML:

```
<div id="target" data-ids="22,11"></div>
```

And JS:

```
var match_ids = jQuery('#target').data("ids");
var match_ids_explode = match_ids.split(',');
```

It splits the ids into array. Works. *However*, if HTML is:

```
<div id="target" data-ids="22"></div>
```

Then `match_ids_explode` is empty. What can I do to the `split(',')` function so it accepts `data-ids="22"` so `match_ids_explode` has one value:

```
match_ids_explode[0] // 22
```

Comment: you can't since, split will require a character to slice the values and put it in the array. You should b checking it if empty then return just the value instead not the array.

Comment: Is there no basic *if* statement I could do to still create an array if the slice value is missing?

Comment: What you describe is exactly the behaviour of `split` -https://jsfiddle.net/ef9ksvyq/ - A single element is created

Comment: @Roljhon if you don't specify a split character, `.split()` will still reeturn an array

Comment: FWIW `"22".split(',');` returns `["22"]`

Comment: @Jamiec Really? See how it doesn't work on my test: https://jsfiddle.net/zg9okko7/1/

Comment: Ah, `.data` coerces it to a number. numbers dont have a `split` method. just call `toString()` on it.

Comment: @Jamiec Please post answer, thanks.

Comment: @2by2 yes it will return an array, I am not saying it won't but that doesn't point to what the OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When there is just a single number in the attribute jQuery helpfully coerces it to a number. This does not have the `split` method. Just use `toString`

```js
var match_ids = jQuery('#target').data("ids");
console.log(match_ids)
var match_ids_explode = match_ids.toString().split(',');
console.log(match_ids_explode.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target" data-ids="22"></div>
```

This will work the same way when there are multiple entries too, so no change needed.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery data method makes assumptions and parses input, so when you have only 22, you get a number instead of a string. 2 possible solutions :

```
match_ids.toString().split(',')
```

Or :

```
var match_ids = jQuery('#target').attr("data-ids");
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of single value i.e. 22, **match_ids** becomes numeric type. you need to convert it to string, then your code will work fine for any condition.

Hope it helps

```js
var match_ids = jQuery('#target').data("ids").toString();
console.log(match_ids);
var match_ids_explode = (match_ids).split(',');
console.log(match_ids_explode);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target" data-ids="22"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the problem is when you have *ids* as "22,11" the *match_ids* is of type 'string' whereas when it is only "22" the type is 'number' and obviously number doesn't have any split function.

You can try doing this:

```
<div id="target" data-ids="'22'"></div>
```

This way *match_ids* will always be a string and *match_ids_explode[0]* will return '22'.